# Identical string return FALSE with '==' in Python, why?

Tags: python, string-comparison

The data string is receive through a socket connexion. When receiving the first example where action variable would = 'IDENTIFY', it works.  But when receiving the second example where action variable would = 'MSG' it does not compare.

And the most bizarre thing, when I use Telnet instead of my socket client both are being compare successfully.  But the string are the same...  Is there a possibility that the string are not encode in the same way?  How can I know?

data example:

```
data = 'IDENTIFY 54143'
or
data = 'MSG allo'

action = data.partition(' ')[0]
if action == "MSG":
    self.sendMessage(data)
elif action == "IDENTIFY":  
    self.sendIdentify(data)
else:
    print "false"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem. To debug it, print or log the `repr()` of `data` and `action`: this will likely show you the cause (probably some non-visible binary byte has snuck into `data`, based on how you obtained it [[which you don't show us]] and hence into `action`).

Comment: '\x00MSG Allo'  that's what I get.  I will try to find how to escape it. Tks a lot!

Tks since i'm new to python I did not know repr().

Comment: @plehoux: you can just `lstrip` this character.