# identical lists return FALSE when trying list1==list2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, match

I've created some code to identify a specific date in a dataset. However, when trying to reference that date and compare it to other dates that contain pertinent data, I can't seem to return a match. It seems odd to me that the below dates would be a list but `type(xyz)` returns `class: 'list'`...

Finding the date:

```
for item in soup.find('td', text='document period end date').parent.find_all('td', {'class':['text']}):
    if len(item.text.strip()) > 0:
        report_date = [item.text.strip()]
        print(report_date) # class: 'list'
```

returns:

```
['mar. 31,  2018']
```

Now let's try to find a match for that date. Here's the code:

```
for filename in filenames:
    print('-----------------------------')
    i = 1
    for item in soup.select('filename:contains("' + filename + '")'):
        if filename in item.text.strip():
            for th in item.find_all('th', {'class':['th']}):
                headers = [th.text.strip()]
                print(headers) # class: 'list'
                if headers == report_date:
                    print('match')
                else:
                    print('no match')
```

returns:

```
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
['sep. 30, 2017']
no match
['6 months ended']
no match
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
['6 months ended']
no match
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
```

try collections.Counter():

```
                if collections.Counter(headers) == collections.Counter(report_date):
                    print('match')
                else:
                    print('no match')
```

no dice:

```
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
['sep. 30, 2017']
no match
['6 months ended']
no match
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
['6 months ended']
no match
['mar. 31, 2018']
no match
```

Try .sort() like some of the below links suggest:

```
                if headers.sort() == report_date.sort():
                    print('match')
                else:
                    print('no match')
```

now it all matches..?:

```
['mar. 31, 2018']
match
['sep. 30, 2017']
match
['6 months ended']
match
['mar. 31, 2018']
match
['6 months ended']
match
['mar. 31, 2018']
match
```

I've not found an applicable or useful answer in the StackOverflow questions [identical string returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493007/identical-string-return-false-with-in-python-why) or [Python '==' incorrectly returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591914/python-incorrectly-returning-false) nor in simple google searches of the topic.

Comment: The number of spaces after the comma differs.  The first instance had 2 spaces, but you tried to match it against versions with only 1.  So of course they compared unequal.  String comparison doesn't return true for "close" matches.  It returns true for identical matches.

Comment: `list.sort` returns `None` (to remind you that the list was sorted as a *side effect*), so of course it’s equal to any other such call.

Comment: @TomKarzes, silly me! Never ceases to amaze me when working through things how simple details such as this can go overlooked and hold things up. Would there be a recommended way to compare "closeness" of two instances?

Comment: @Jkiefn1That's a pretty broad topic, but one thing you could easily do is reduce all sequences of white space (spaces, tabs, etc.) to a single space.  Or you could remove *all* spaces and just compare the resulting sequences of non-space characters.  It really depends on what best suits your needs.